# update array with carried over values in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need to carry over a value from previous round's total score,

```java
public static double[] CFArray(ArrayList<game> list) {
    double[] cf = new double[list.size()];
    //current cf equals to the previous total score
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            cf[0] = 0;
        } else {
            cf[i] = list.get(i - 1).getTotalScore();
        }
    }
    return cf;        
}
```

`list` is an array list of objects that the `getTotalscore` method belongs to. When it is the first round, the cf value should be 0. This method is either giving me `indexoutofbounds` error or wrong values.. what should I do now?

Comment: It's kinda hard to answer with knowing how is your `list` looks like, can you provide an example?

Comment: Please provide some basic input and the expected output.  It is not clear how you get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, and _why_ the values you get are _wrong_.

Comment: You do not need to check for `i == 0` to initialize `cf[0]` to 0, it is done by default when the array is created.  So you may just start iterating from 1: `for (for int i = 1; ...)`